How to use an array of promises with v-data-table
I have a v-data-table that is used in a table component I am building out. I pass data as a prop, which then I do a few things to clean up, then also run an async function which grabs some data from an api as follows:
//load cloud storage data
const cleanData = ref<any[]>()

const loadThumbnails = async (dmcp_tab_id : number, dmcp_box_id : string) => {
  let attempts : number = 1
  const result = ref<CloudStorage | null>()
  do {
      attempts=attempts+1
      result.value = await documentStore.getCloudStorage(dmcp_tab_id, dmcp_box_id)
    } while (result.value!.thumbnail == "" && attempts <= 5)
  
  return result.value?.thumbnail
}

const loadCloudStorageData = () => {
  cleanData.value = props.data
  cleanData.value = props.data.map(async (item) => { return {...item, when_uploaded: dayjs(item.when_uploaded).format('MM/DD/YYYY'), thumbnail: await loadThumbnails(item.dmcp_tab_id, item.dmcp_box_id)}})
}

loadCloudStorageData()
watch(props.data, () => {
  loadCloudStorageData()
})

When I look at the cleanData and console.log() it it is an array of promises so nothing loads into the v-data-table. However, if I were to remove this await and async thumbnail then it will load everything as fine into v-data-table. I am not sure how to handle promises with v-data-table.

If you have an array of promises then you probably want Promise.all

How would I implement that in the scenario above?

cleanData.value = await Promise.all(props.data.map(...)) is potentially the only fix needed

This isn't specific to Vue but about handling an array of promises. For that, we need Promise.all.


// Helper function to simulate fetching data from an api
async function fetchDataFromApi(data, delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data);
    }, delay);
  });
}

async function fetchAllData() {
  try {
  
    const promises = [
      fetchDataFromApi({ name: 'Bill' } , 500),
      fetchDataFromApi({ name: 'Ted' }, 0),
      fetchDataFromApi({ name: 'Rufus' }, 200),
    ];

    console.log('before Promise.all', promises)

    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    
    console.log('after Promise.all', results);
 
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Oops', error);
  }
}

fetchAllData();



